# SQL - Are columns always corresponding?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT max(date) as lastdt,name,col1  FROM `consumption` group by name
```

In the above query, are values of `col1`,`max(date)` and `name` taken from the same row?

Comment: No, the value of `col1` is indeterminate.

Comment: Thanks for that quick reply.
I want the `col1` value to correspond with the other two values. How can I do that?

Comment: Group by name and co1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL allows for non-aggregated columns to appear in the `SELECT` clause of a query. However the values of these columns are indeterminate.

If you want to get the `col1` value that corresponds to the record having the maximum `date` value, then you will have to do an additional join:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `consumption` AS t1
JOIN (SELECT max(`date`) as lastdt, name  
      FROM `consumption` 
      group by name) AS t2
ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.`date` = t2.lastdt
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: they may be or may not be. See mysql documentation on [how mysql handles the group by clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

> [MySql] is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the
>   same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what
>   you want.

For the long answer you need to read the entire page I linked above, that will give you the complete picture.

To sum it up: under certain configuration settings, mysql interprets group by clauses in a relaxed mode allowing fields in the select list that are not in the group by clause, nor are subject of any grouping function (such as sum()). In this case, mysql is free to choose any value for such field from the given group.